# How to loop through multiple blocks of a file having common pattern in php

Tags: php, loops

I have designed a code which fetches data from a log file and uploads it to the database. I am able to connect to the database. This code is working fine when i have one POST block. However when my file holds more than one POST block it replaces the previous data and uploads the last block data. Can someone help how can i loop in my code to upload each POST block separately.
My code:

```html
<pre><?php
class logAgent
{
 const CONFIG_FILENAME = "data_config.ini";
    
    private $_dbConn;
    private $_config;
    
 function __construct()
    {
        $this->_loadConfig();
        
        
        $this->_dbConn = oci_connect($this->_config['db_usrnm'],
            $this->_config['db_pwd'],
            $this->_config['hostnm_sid']);
    }
 
 public function uploadLogs(){
        
        //Array of all the files present in the directory
        $f = fopen($this->_config['uploadedRegistry'], 'r');
        $contents = [];
        while (FALSE !== ($row = fgetcsv($f, 1000, $this->_config['filenameTimeSeparator']))){
            $contents[] = $row[0];
        }
  
        $result = array_diff(scandir($this->_config['logspath']), ['.','..'], $contents);
        foreach($result as $r){
            $this->uploadLog($r);
        }
    }
 
 private function _loadConfig()
    {
        // Loads config
        $path = dirname(__FILE__) . '/' . self::CONFIG_FILENAME;
        $this->_config = parse_ini_file($path) ;
    }
 public function uploadLog($filename) {
        
        $filename = trim($this->_config['logspath'] . trim($filename));
  
  if(file_exists($filename)){
   
   $fh = fopen($filename,"r");
   $array = array();
   $started = false;
   
   while (!feof($fh)) {
    $line = trim(fgets($fh));
    if($started) {
    
  
     if(!ctype_space($line)&&!empty($line)&&!preg_match('#-$#',$line)){
                if(strpos($line,'POST')===0){
                    $data=array_map('trim',str_getcsv($line,' ',''));
                    $temp['POST']=array_slice($data,1,2);
                }
                elseif(strpos($line,'GET')===0){
                    $data=array_map('trim',str_getcsv($line,' ',''));
                    $temp['GET']=array_slice($data,1,2);
                }
                else{
                    if(isset($A)){
                        $data=array_map('trim',str_getcsv($line,' ',''));
                        $data[0].=$data[1];
                        unset($data[1]);
                        $temp['Stamp']=array_combine(['REQUEST_TIME','text','IP_ADDRESS','port','ip','s_i'],$data);
                        unset($A);
                    }else{

                        $data=array_map('trim',str_getcsv($line,':',''));
                        if(isset($data[1])){
                            if($data[0]=='Keep-Alive'){
                                $d=explode(',',$data[1]);
                                $d[0]=array_map('trim',explode('=',$d[0]));
                                $d[1]=array_map('trim',explode('=',$d[1]));
                                $temp[$data[0]]=[$d[0][0]=>$d[0][1],$d[1][0]=>$d[1][1]];
                            }else{
                                $temp[$data[0]]=$data[1];
                            }
                        }elseif(strpos($data[0],'HTTP')===0){
                            $data=explode(' ',$data[0]);
                            $temp['HTTP']=array_combine(['version','status','message'],$data);
                        }else{
                            $temp['Query_string']=$data[0];
                        }
                    }
                }
         }


        if(strpos($line, "--") === 0 && strpos($line, "-Z-") > 0) {
            $started = false;
            $array[$tmp] = $temp;
            $temp=[];
            $tmp++;
        }
      }
      if(strpos($line, "--") === 0 && strpos($line, "-A-") > 0) {
        $A=true;
        $started = true;
        $tmp=trim($line);
        $temp=[];
      }
    }
    fclose($fh);

foreach($array as $k=>$value){
    if(isset($value["POST"])){
  
        $CLIENT_REQUEST = $value['POST'][0];
  $IP_ADDRESS = ($value['Stamp']['IP_ADDRESS']);
  $tmp1 = explode('+', ($value['Stamp']['REQUEST_TIME']));
  $REQUEST_TIME = (str_replace('[', '',$tmp1[0]));
  $X_REQUESTED_WITH =($value['X-Requested-With']);
  $RESPONSE_CODE = ($value['HTTP']['status']);
  $TANUSER = ($value['tanuser']);
  $COOKIES = ($value['cookie']);
  $tmp = explode(';', ($value['cookie']));
  $AUTHSCHEME = (str_replace('authscheme=','', $tmp[0]));
  $AUTHMARKET = (str_replace('authMarket=','', $tmp[1]));
  $SIZEOFOBJECT = ($value['Content-Length']);
  $ENV = ($value['env']);
  $OUTPUT_DATA = ($value['Query_string']);
  
    }elseif(isset($value["GET"])){
        //var_dump($value['tanuser']);
    }
}
  $statement = "INSERT INTO AUDIT_LOGS(IP_ADDRESS, 
    REQUEST_TIME, 
    CLIENT_REQUEST,
    RESPONSE_CODE,
    SIZEOFOBJECT,
    COOKIES, 
    AUTHSCHEME,
    AUTHMARKET,
    X_REQUESTED_WITH,
    ENV,
    TANUSER, 
    OUTPUT_DATA) 
                values(:IP_ADDRESS,to_date(:REQUEST_TIME, 'DD/Mon/YYYY:HH24:MI:SS' ) , :CLIENT_REQUEST, :RESPONSE_CODE , :SIZEOFOBJECT, :COOKIES, :AUTHSCHEME, :AUTHMARKET, :X_REQUESTED_WITH, :ENV, :TANUSER, :OUTPUT_DATA )";
                
  //Preparing an Oracle statement for execution
  $compiled = oci_parse($this->_dbConn, $statement);
     
  //binding values to named parameters

  oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':IP_ADDRESS', $IP_ADDRESS);
  $REQUEST_TIME = str_replace('"', '', $REQUEST_TIME);
  oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':REQUEST_TIME', $REQUEST_TIME);
  oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':CLIENT_REQUEST', $CLIENT_REQUEST);
  oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':RESPONSE_CODE', $RESPONSE_CODE);
  oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':SIZEOFOBJECT', $SIZEOFOBJECT); 
  oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':COOKIES', $COOKIES); 
  oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':AUTHSCHEME', $AUTHSCHEME);
  oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':AUTHMARKET', $AUTHMARKET); 
  oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':X_REQUESTED_WITH', $X_REQUESTED_WITH);
  oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':ENV', $ENV); 
  oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':TANUSER', $TANUSER);
  oci_bind_by_name($compiled,':OUTPUT_DATA', $OUTPUT_DATA);
     
  //Executing statement
  oci_execute($compiled, OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS);

   //$this->updateRegistry($filename);
   return TRUE;
  } 
  else{
    throw new Exception("File doesnot exist");
   }
 }
 
 public function sendEmail(Exception $e){
        
        $sent = mail($this->_config['recipients'], $this->_config['notificationSubject'], $e);
    }
    
    public function updateRegistry($filename)
    {
        
        $uploadedfilename = fopen($this->_config['uploadedRegistry'], "a");
        fwrite($uploadedfilename, basename($filename . date($this->_config['filenameTimeSeparator'] . 'Ymdhi', time())) . PHP_EOL);
    } 
}

try {
    $logAgent = new logAgent();
    $logAgent->uploadLogs();
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    $logAgent->sendEmail($e);
}

?>
```

My file :

```html
--49160000-A--
[30/Aug/2018:13:41:19 +0200] W4fX34HC0Xb8YDuIqk5YOgAAAD4 127.0.0.1 55064 127.0.0.1 80
--49160000-B--
GET /FormValidation/page1.php HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: http://localhost/FormValidation/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
tanuser: 00198343

--49160000-F--
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.35
Content-Length: 851
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

--49160000-Z--

--84670001-A--
[31/Aug/2018:13:41:25 +0200] W4fX5YHC0Xb8YDuIqk5YOwAAAD8 127.0.0.1 55065 127.0.0.1 80
--84670001-B--
POST /FormValidation/validation.php HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 33
Accept: */*
Origin: http://localhost
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
cookie: authscheme=abc;authMarket=abfg
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://localhost/FormValidation/page1.php
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
tanuser: 00198343
env: dev

--84670001-C--
name1=test&email1=ssn%40gmail.com
--84670000-F--
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.35
Content-Length: 17
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

--84670001-Z--

--84670002-A--
[31/Aug/2018:13:41:25 +0200] W4fX5YHC0Xb8YDuIqk5YOwAAAD8 127.0.0.1 55065 127.0.0.1 80
--84670002-B--
POST /FormValidation/validation.php HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 33
Accept: */*
Origin: http://localhost
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
cookie: authscheme=abc;authMarket=abfg
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://localhost/FormValidation/page1.php
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
tanuser: 00198343
env: dev

--84670002-C--
name1=test1&email1=ssn1%40gmail.com
--84670000-F--
HTTP/1.1 400 OK
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.35
Content-Length: 17
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

--84670002-Z--
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to move the database insertion part inside the foreach loop.

```
<?php
class logAgent
{
    const CONFIG_FILENAME = "data_config.ini";

    private $_dbConn;
    private $_config;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->_loadConfig();


        $this->_dbConn = oci_connect($this->_config['db_usrnm'],
            $this->_config['db_pwd'],
            $this->_config['hostnm_sid']);
    }

    public function uploadLogs(){

        //Array of all the files present in the directory
        $f = fopen($this->_config['uploadedRegistry'], 'r');
        $contents = [];
        while (FALSE !== ($row = fgetcsv($f, 1000, $this->_config['filenameTimeSeparator']))){
            $contents[] = $row[0];
        }

        $result = array_diff(scandir($this->_config['logspath']), ['.','..'], $contents);
        foreach($result as $r){
            $this->uploadLog($r);
        }
    }

    private function _loadConfig()
    {
        // Loads config
        $path = dirname(__FILE__) . '/' . self::CONFIG_FILENAME;
        $this->_config = parse_ini_file($path) ;
    }
    public function uploadLog($filename) {

        $filename = trim($this->_config['logspath'] . trim($filename));

        if(file_exists($filename)){

            $fh = fopen($filename,"r");
            $array = array();
            $started = false;

            while (!feof($fh)) {
                $line = trim(fgets($fh));
                if($started) {


                    if(!ctype_space($line)&&!empty($line)&&!preg_match('#-$#',$line)){
                if(strpos($line,'POST')===0){
                    $data=array_map('trim',str_getcsv($line,' ',''));
                    $temp['POST']=array_slice($data,1,2);
                }
                elseif(strpos($line,'GET')===0){
                    $data=array_map('trim',str_getcsv($line,' ',''));
                    $temp['GET']=array_slice($data,1,2);
                }
                else{
                    if(isset($A)){
                        $data=array_map('trim',str_getcsv($line,' ',''));
                        $data[0].=$data[1];
                        unset($data[1]);
                        $temp['Stamp']=array_combine(['REQUEST_TIME','text','IP_ADDRESS','port','ip','s_i'],$data);
                        unset($A);
                    }else{

                        $data=array_map('trim',str_getcsv($line,':',''));
                        if(isset($data[1])){
                            if($data[0]=='Keep-Alive'){
                                $d=explode(',',$data[1]);
                                $d[0]=array_map('trim',explode('=',$d[0]));
                                $d[1]=array_map('trim',explode('=',$d[1]));
                                $temp[$data[0]]=[$d[0][0]=>$d[0][1],$d[1][0]=>$d[1][1]];
                            }else{
                                $temp[$data[0]]=$data[1];
                            }
                        }elseif(strpos($data[0],'HTTP')===0){
                            $data=explode(' ',$data[0]);
                            $temp['HTTP']=array_combine(['version','status','message'],$data);
                        }else{
                            $temp['Query_string']=$data[0];
                        }
                    }
                }
         }


        if(strpos($line, "--") === 0 && strpos($line, "-Z-") > 0) {
            $started = false;
            $array[$tmp] = $temp;
            $temp=[];
            $tmp++;
        }
      }
      if(strpos($line, "--") === 0 && strpos($line, "-A-") > 0) {
        $A=true;
        $started = true;
        $tmp=trim($line);
        $temp=[];
      }
    }
    fclose($fh);

        foreach($array as $k=>$value){
            if(isset($value["POST"])){

                $CLIENT_REQUEST = $value['POST'][0];
                $IP_ADDRESS = ($value['Stamp']['IP_ADDRESS']);
                $tmp1 = explode('+', ($value['Stamp']['REQUEST_TIME']));
                $REQUEST_TIME = (str_replace('[', '',$tmp1[0]));
                $X_REQUESTED_WITH =($value['X-Requested-With']);
                $RESPONSE_CODE = ($value['HTTP']['status']);
                $TANUSER = ($value['tanuser']);
                $COOKIES = ($value['cookie']);
                $tmp = explode(';', ($value['cookie']));
                $AUTHSCHEME = (str_replace('authscheme=','', $tmp[0]));
                $AUTHMARKET = (str_replace('authMarket=','', $tmp[1]));
                $SIZEOFOBJECT = ($value['Content-Length']);
                $ENV = ($value['env']);
                $OUTPUT_DATA = ($value['Query_string']);
                $statement = "INSERT INTO AUDIT_LOGS(IP_ADDRESS, 
                        REQUEST_TIME, 
                        CLIENT_REQUEST,
                        RESPONSE_CODE,
                        SIZEOFOBJECT,
                        COOKIES, 
                        AUTHSCHEME,
                        AUTHMARKET,
                        X_REQUESTED_WITH,
                        ENV,
                        TANUSER, 
                        OUTPUT_DATA) 
                        values(:IP_ADDRESS,to_date(:REQUEST_TIME, 'DD/Mon/YYYY:HH24:MI:SS' ) , :CLIENT_REQUEST, :RESPONSE_CODE , :SIZEOFOBJECT, :COOKIES, :AUTHSCHEME, :AUTHMARKET, :X_REQUESTED_WITH, :ENV, :TANUSER, :OUTPUT_DATA )";

                //Preparing an Oracle statement for execution
                $compiled = oci_parse($this->_dbConn, $statement);

                //binding values to named parameters

                oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':IP_ADDRESS', $IP_ADDRESS);
                $REQUEST_TIME = str_replace('"', '', $REQUEST_TIME);
                oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':REQUEST_TIME', $REQUEST_TIME);
                oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':CLIENT_REQUEST', $CLIENT_REQUEST);
                oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':RESPONSE_CODE', $RESPONSE_CODE);
                oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':SIZEOFOBJECT', $SIZEOFOBJECT);    
                oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':COOKIES', $COOKIES);  
                oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':AUTHSCHEME', $AUTHSCHEME);
                oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':AUTHMARKET', $AUTHMARKET);    
                oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':X_REQUESTED_WITH', $X_REQUESTED_WITH);
                oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':ENV', $ENV);  
                oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':TANUSER', $TANUSER);
                oci_bind_by_name($compiled,':OUTPUT_DATA', $OUTPUT_DATA);

                //Executing statement
                oci_execute($compiled, OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS);

            }elseif(isset($value["GET"])){
                //var_dump($value['tanuser']);
            }
        }


            //$this->updateRegistry($filename);
            return TRUE;
        }   
        else{
                throw new Exception("File doesnot exist");
            }
    }

    public function sendEmail(Exception $e){

        $sent = mail($this->_config['recipients'], $this->_config['notificationSubject'], $e);
    }

    public function updateRegistry($filename)
    {

        $uploadedfilename = fopen($this->_config['uploadedRegistry'], "a");
        fwrite($uploadedfilename, basename($filename . date($this->_config['filenameTimeSeparator'] . 'Ymdhi', time())) . PHP_EOL);
    } 
}

try {
    $logAgent = new logAgent();
    $logAgent->uploadLogs();
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    $logAgent->sendEmail($e);
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your help :)